# How to open a modal with a navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I am opening a modal and in this modal I want to use a viewcontroller but also a navigation controller which should be the rootViewController (right?).

Is the controller or the navigation controller rootview here?

*This is my code:*

```
controller = DetailsController.alloc.init

appsNavController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(controller)

self.presentModalViewController(appsNavController, animated:true)
```

*I get this message, don´t know if it is related*

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

*I have a rootview controller in the app delegate*

```
window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
window.makeKeyAndVisible
window.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Comment: is `tabBarController` non-`nil`?

Comment: Without seeing more of your app delegate code its hard to say, but you are using a tab bar controller, so have you initialized your tab bar controller with the navigation controller which in turn is initalized with your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling `window.makeKeyAndVisible`
when there is no rootviewcontroller.
Interchange the lines

```
window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
window.rootViewController = tabBarController
window.makeKeyAndVisible
```

This may help.

And make sure you have allocated `tabBarController` with valid `viewControllers`.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the message remains.